# Activity onRestart()'s utility

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I do not intend to make this a discussion around, "what is onRestart()" but the [latest documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) from Google about the Activity lifecycle has left out the role for `onRestart()`. From personal experience, I haven't overridden `onRestart()` ever.

On searching about the utility of `onRestart()`, other SO answers don't seem to reach a conclusion as well.

I wouldn't prefer any *by the book* definition for `onRestart()` and so practically speaking, what utility `onRestart()` might hold? Has anyone effectively overridden it?

**EDIT 1:** Example based(and production scenario) answers would be really insightful in this case and would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestart()) gives one example:

> For activities that are using raw `Cursor` objects (instead of creating
>   them through `managedQuery(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String[],
>   java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String)`, this is
>   usually the place where the cursor should be requeried (because you
>   had deactivated it in `onStop()`.

In general, if there is any activity that you "deactivated" in `onStop()`, you can reactive it in `onRestart()`.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply but can't we just reactivate it in onStart(), checking `if(not already activated)`?

Comment: I suppose. you can. However, `onRestart()` gives you more information that you can use. It doesn't mean you MUST use it.